# iphone image gets rotate while downloading from sever

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, exif

I am trying to upload camera images from iPhone to my web server but some how the images change it's orientation when i download them from server.This only happens with camera images and not simple images uploaded to device from my machine.Plz help me.

i have use this condition to rotate image on server side:

//obj will be Orientation passed while uploading image on server its value will be either 1 or 3or  6 or 8

```
switch ((ushort)obj)
               {
                   case 1: //up
                       return 0;
                   case 3: //down
                       return 180;
                   case 6: //left
                       return 90;
                   case 8: //right
                       return 270;
                   default:
                       return 0;
               }
```

But still i am getting the same problem

Here is my code for Upload image:

```
-(void)uploadSingleFile
{
    if(!self.objWebServices.bSyncWasOn)
    {
        NSLog(@"STOP upload Single File RETURN");
        [self Call_SaveSyncedImageID];
        return;
    }
    SyncItem* item = [arrSelSyncItemIDS objectAtIndex:nSyncItemIndex];

    if(item.nType == SYNC_STATUS_NOT_SELECTED || item.nType == SYNC_STATUS_SYNC_DONE)
    {
        nSyncItemIndex = nSyncItemIndex + 1;
        if([arrSelSyncItemIDS count] > nSyncItemIndex)
        {
            NSLog(@"Called uploadSingleFile");
            [self uploadSingleFile];
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            //[self LoadImages:!bShowHideSyncImages];
            [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
            [BtnStopSync setTitle:@"Start sync" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            self.objWebServices.bSyncWasOn = NO;
            self.objWebServices.isFileUpload = NO;

            if( [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"Notification_State"] ) // Setting Switch Bool
            {
                UIAlertView *Alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"winkflash" message:@"*** Sync completed successfully." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [Alert show];
            }
        }
    }
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *srtprefSessionId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[prefs objectForKey:@"prefSessionId"]];

    BOOL isTrash = FALSE;   
    NSString *StrPath = @"/Pictures/";      //Change 
    ALAsset* temp = item.itemAsset;
    NSDate* assetDate = (NSDate*)[temp valueForProperty:@"ALAssetPropertyDate"];

    NSString* strID = @"";
    strID = [[temp valueForProperty:@"ALAssetPropertyURLs"] description];
    strID = [strID stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

    NSString* strImageType = @"";
    if ([strID rangeOfString:@"jpg"].location != NSNotFound || [strID rangeOfString:@"JPG"].location != NSNotFound ){
        strImageType = @"jpg";
    }
    else if ([strID rangeOfString:@"png"].location != NSNotFound || [strID rangeOfString:@"PNG"].location != NSNotFound )
        strImageType = @"png";


    NSDateFormatter* df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
    NSString *result = [df stringFromDate:assetDate];

    NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [assetDate timeIntervalSince1970];
    ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [temp defaultRepresentation];

    //------------------ metadata -------------------------------------------------------
    NSDictionary *imageMetadata = [rep metadata];
    NSString *strOrt=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[imageMetadata valueForKey:@"Orientation"]];
    NSString *strOrientation;

    if([strOrt isEqualToString:@"6"])
    {
        strOrientation=@"1";
    }
    if([strOrt isEqualToString:@"8"])
    {
        strOrientation=@"3";
    }
    if([strOrt isEqualToString:@"3"])
    {
        strOrientation=@"6";
    }
    if([strOrt isEqualToString:@"1"])
    {
        strOrientation=@"8";
    }
    NSLog(@"print strOrientation:%@",strOrientation);
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    StrPath = [StrPath stringByAppendingFormat:@"%d.%@",(int)timeInterval,strImageType];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[rep fullResolutionImage]];
    NSData *dataObj = nil;
    dataObj = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    NSString* StrFileData = [Base64 encode:dataObj];
    NSString* strFileHash = [dataObj md5Test];

    //----------------------------------------------------
    NSMutableDictionary *DictRequest = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [DictRequest setObject:srtprefSessionId forKey:@"SessionId"];
    [DictRequest setObject:StrPath forKey:@"Path"];
    [DictRequest setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:isTrash] forKey:@"UploadDirectlyToTrashbin"];
    [DictRequest setObject:StrFileData forKey:@"FileData"];
    [DictRequest setObject:strFileHash forKey:@"FileHash"];
    [DictRequest setObject:result forKey:@"DateCreated"];

    BOOL isNULL = [self stringIsEmpty:strOrientation];
    if(!isNULL)
    {
        [DictRequest setObject:strOrientation forKey:@"Orientation"];
    }


    NSString *jsonString = [DictRequest JSONRepresentation];
    NSString *strUrl=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",FileUpload_URL];
    NSURL *url1=[NSURL URLWithString:strUrl];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url1];
    [request setTimeoutInterval:60.0];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    NSData *postData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[postData length]];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];


    if(theConnection)
        [self Set2Defaults];

    theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    [SVProgressHUD dismiss];

    if(theConnection)
        webData = [NSMutableData data];
    else
        NSLog(@"Connection Failed !!!");
}
```

Comment: What kind of an Object is `obj`? Show more code, otherwise your never gonna get a helpful answer.

Comment: Can you put your code for uploading images, so we can more figure out.. what problem may be?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is due to the way orientation is stored within UIImage.

I use this function inside a category on UIImage.

```
- (UIImage *)fixOrientation {

    // No-op if the orientation is already correct
    if (self.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationUp) return self;

    // We need to calculate the proper transformation to make the image upright.
    // We do it in 2 steps: Rotate if Left/Right/Down, and then flip if Mirrored.
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

    switch (self.imageOrientation) {
        case UIImageOrientationDown:
        case UIImageOrientationDownMirrored:
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, self.size.width, self.size.height);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationLeft:
        case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, self.size.width, 0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI_2);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationRight:
        case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, 0, self.size.height);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, -M_PI_2);
            break;
        case UIImageOrientationUp:
        case UIImageOrientationUpMirrored:
            break;
    }

    switch (self.imageOrientation) {
        case UIImageOrientationUpMirrored:
        case UIImageOrientationDownMirrored:
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, self.size.width, 0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1, 1);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:
        case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, self.size.height, 0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1, 1);
            break;
        case UIImageOrientationUp:
        case UIImageOrientationDown:
        case UIImageOrientationLeft:
        case UIImageOrientationRight:
            break;
    }

    // Now we draw the underlying CGImage into a new context, applying the transform
    // calculated above.
    CGContextRef ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, self.size.width, self.size.height,
                                             CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(self.CGImage), 0,
                                             CGImageGetColorSpace(self.CGImage),
                                             CGImageGetBitmapInfo(self.CGImage));
    CGContextConcatCTM(ctx, transform);
    switch (self.imageOrientation) {
        case UIImageOrientationLeft:
        case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:
        case UIImageOrientationRight:
        case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:
            // Grr...
            CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0,0,self.size.height,self.size.width), self.CGImage);
            break;

        default:
            CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0,0,self.size.width,self.size.height), self.CGImage);
            break;
    }

    // And now we just create a new UIImage from the drawing context
    CGImageRef cgimg = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(ctx);
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgimg];
    CGContextRelease(ctx);
    CGImageRelease(cgimg);
    return img;
}
```

Just run this when getting the image from the imagePicker.

Then when you upload and download it will keep the orientation.

Comment: i am not gettting image from image picker first i have load all images from my camara galary to my app and after getting all images i have selected perticular image to upload on server

Comment: The problem is still the same though. The UIImage stores separate data that tells the app what orientation to display it at. Your server doesn't. When you download the image back again the orientation data is gone and you get the wrong orientation. You can either try to fix the server side or just use this category on the image before uploading :D

Comment: where should i call this function - (UIImage *)fixOrientation { @Fogmeister

Comment: First, this will only work as a category on UIImage. Add the file that way first. At some point in your app you will have a UIImage that you are going to upload to the server. Call this on the image before uploading it. i.e. `image = [image fixOrientation];  [image uploadImageToServer];`

Comment: i have changed my code :   StrPath = [StrPath stringByAppendingFormat:@"%d.%@",(int)timeInterval,strImageType];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[rep fullResolutionImage]];   but its still not i get rotated image :( @Fogmeister
    NSData *dataObj = nil;
     UIImage *image1 = [image fixOrientation];
    dataObj = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image1);
    NSString* StrFileData = [Base64 encode:dataObj];
    NSString* strFileHash = [dataObj md5Test];

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
UIImage *sourceImage = ... // Our image
CGRect selectionRect = CGRectMake(100.0, 100.0, 300.0, 400.0);
CGImageRef resultImageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(sourceImage.CGImage,
selectionRect);
UIImage *resultImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:resultImageRef];
```

And

```
CGRect TransformCGRectForUIImageOrientation(CGRect source, UIImageOrientation orientation, CGSize imageSize) {
switch (orientation) {
case UIImageOrientationLeft: { // EXIF #8
  CGAffineTransform txTranslate = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(imageSize.height, 0.0);
  CGAffineTransform txCompound = CGAffineTransformRotate(txTranslate,M_PI_2);
  return CGRectApplyAffineTransform(source, txCompound);
}
case UIImageOrientationDown: { // EXIF #3
  CGAffineTransform txTranslate = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(imageSize.width, imageSize.height);
  CGAffineTransform txCompound = CGAffineTransformRotate(txTranslate,M_PI);
  return CGRectApplyAffineTransform(source, txCompound);
}
case UIImageOrientationRight: { // EXIF #6
  CGAffineTransform txTranslate = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, imageSize.width);
  CGAffineTransform txCompound = CGAffineTransformRotate(txTranslate,M_PI + M_PI_2);
  return CGRectApplyAffineTransform(source, txCompound);
}
case UIImageOrientationUp: // EXIF #1 - do nothing
  default: // EXIF 2,4,5,7 - ignore
  return source;
}
}
  ...
UIImage *sourceImage = ... // Our image
 CGRect selectionRect = CGRectMake(100.0, 100.0, 300.0, 400.0);
CGRect transformedRect = TransformCGRectForUIImageOrientation(selectionRect,  sourceImage.imageOrientation, sourceImage.size);
CGImageRef resultImageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(sourceImage.CGImage, transformedRect);
UIImage *resultImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:resultImageRef];
```